# multi-level nested states not loading template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have setup my states as below, as you can see first state is abstract, and all second level states (list, edit and new) loads perfectly, but my third level states (passengers) is not loading, it stays on edit state UI. What I might be doing wrong.

Here is link to plunker, click on contacts, then first contact and you will see a link "messages", if you click on that, it will not change anything.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qclHQg?p=preview

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('trips', {
            parent: 'app',
            abstract: true,
            url: '/trips',
            data: {
                role: ['Administrators']
            }
        })
        .state('trips.list', {
            url: '',
            component: 'tripList'
        })
        .state('trips.trip-edit', {
            url: '/{id:[0-9]+}',
            component: 'tripEdit',
            onEnter: function () {
                console.log("entering trips.trip-edit");
            },
            onExit: function () {
                console.log("exiting trips.trip-edit");
            }
        })
        .state('trips.trip-edit.passengers', {
            url: '/passengers',
            //component: 'tripPassengers', using views below
            views: { '@app': { template: '<trip-passengers />' } },
            onEnter: function () {
                console.log("entering trips.trip-edit.passengers");
            },
            onExit: function () {
                console.log("exiting trips.trip-edit.passengers");
            }
        })
        .state('trips.trip-new', {
            url: '/new',
            component: 'tripNew'
        });
};
```

@ramon answer was good, but I solved it, modified that by adding views section in passenger state, and my component was automatically wired in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are working with angular ui router states you need to understand a concept.

All states will try to render in the parent view, but when you are nesting states you may encounter a problem that there is not that component on the parent view.

For example: your `trips.trip-edit` state, probably does not have a place to `trips.trip-edit.passengers` render.

made a fork of your plunker and made it work

http://plnkr.co/edit/wT6rTPAvmfjnrNbt0WFk?p=preview

I'm in a rush here, let me try to explain the relevant parts here.

First of all I changed the index.html ui-view to a 'named view', that's when we pass a name for that ui-view, `ui-view="main"`, so i called it main

Then we have to specify in all our routes (states), where their templates will render, which view.

```
views: {
  'main' : {
    templateUrl: ...,
    controller: ...
  }
}
```

notice that in a nested view I had to put an AT (@).

```
views: {
  'main@' : {
    templateUrl: ...,
    controller: ...
  }
}
```

That @ tells angular to look for a main starting from your root, because there is nothing after @, it's an absolute path. When you don't use @ it's a relative path. It's better explain here in the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

So if you want to render a view inside another named view inside about.html for example you could do the following

```
views: {
  'another@about' : {
    templateUrl: ...,
    controller: ...
  }
}
```

That would look for `ui-view="another"` inside about state template, that is about.html

Comment: you are saying that i can request child state to use parent's parent ui-view?

Comment: yes, you can check the documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names

Comment: I have added a plunker, can you look into that and make required changes

Comment: @ZafarIqbal join here a chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146449/help-zafar

Comment: @ZafarIqbal I made brief to you in my answer, see ya